# can a ColorFunction have side effects?

Tags: graphics, front-end, evaluation, function-construction, color

Can anyone explain this (to me) odd behavior. If I run this code once (fresh kernel) it works as intended.

```
data = Table[Random[Real], {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
mycf[x_] := (AppendTo[hdat, x]; Hue[x])
hdat = {};
Show[Graphics[Raster[data, ColorFunction -> mycf]]]
Print["hdat len", Length[hdat]]
Histogram[hdat]
```

If I execute the same thing a second time the plot is generated but the `hdat` array is left empty.  It seems some sort of caching is happening??

Edit - an even smaller example to illustrate the issue:

```
mycf[x_] := (value = 1; Hue[0])
value = 0
Show[Graphics[Raster[{{0}}, ColorFunction -> mycf]]]
value
    ------------next cell
value
```

Further clue... it turns out that any `ColorFunction` specified gets wrapped in `Dynamic[]`:
If you do:

```
Graphics[Raster[{{0}}]]
Graphics[Raster[{{0}}, ColorFunction -> (Black &)]]
```

with dynamic updating disabled the first form works while the second does not.
With that in mind, following `Show[]` in my example with `FinishDynamic[]` seems to do the trick.

Comment: I stuck a `Pause[.05]` in between the `Graphics` and `Histogram` and it worked as you would expect.

Comment: I'd have used `Sow[]`/`Reap[]` instead of `AppendTo[]` myself...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certain things such as `Graphics` objects are handled by the Front End rather than the Kernel.  An even simpler example of the behavior you question is this:

```
mycf[x_] := (Print["FE eval"]; Hue[0])
gr = Graphics[Raster[{{0}}, ColorFunction -> mycf]];
```

Upon evaluation nothing is printed, however if we then evaluate `gr` separately so that the graphic prints we also get `"FE eval"` printed to the Messages window.  We get this every time `gr` is evaluated in a manner than displays the graphic.  If we request the InputForm instead we see that the `ColorFunction` is held unevaluated in the expression:

```
gr // InputForm
```

> ```
> Graphics[Raster[{{0}}, ColorFunction -> mycf]]
> ```

This expression is not further evaluated until it is passed to the FrontEnd (which calls the Kernel for evaluations beyond its scope).

Answer (score 1):

Check this with `Dynamic`!

```
data = Table[Random[Real], {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
hdat = {};
mycf[x_] := (AppendTo[hdat, x]; Hue[x]);
GraphicsRow[{Show[Graphics[Raster[data, ColorFunction -> mycf]]], 
 Dynamic@Histogram[hdat, Frame -> True, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{height}, Hue[height]], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLabel -> "hdat length :" <> ToString[Length[hdat]]]}]
```

[image]

I guess `ColorFunction` is not responsible for the odd behavior. Once you evaluate the list `hdat` then it is available to the front end to display. This has to be done in a different cell or else some trick like the above. Or as chris commented by defining `mycf` differently `mycf[x_] := (hdat=AppendTo[hdat, x]; Hue[x])` so that the symbol `hdat` is evaluated in the kernel each time the color-function is called.

BR

Comment: ahh that gives a clue. In fact if we acess the value in a new cell the updated value is available.  So is this a Bug or an undocumenred feature?