# Caching of Graph Graphics

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, caching

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23542/4330), Simon Woods concludes that when you display an expression with head graph more than once, something is getting stored somewhere. I looked into it too and found out this only happens if you tie the expression with head graph to a symbol. Evaluating the symbol a second time will no longer print messages and results of random numbers are the same. Consider this example

```
g=Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, 
   VertexShapeFunction -> ({Random[] // Hue, Disk[Print["VSF"]; #, 0.05]} &)]
```

--prints--> messages
--displays-> a graph with pretty colors

```
g
```

--displays--> a graph with the same pretty colors (and does not print messages)

even though

```
g // FullForm // InputForm
```

returns

```
(*output*)
FullForm[Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {DirectedEdge[1, 2], DirectedEdge[2, 3], 
      DirectedEdge[3, 1]}, {VertexShapeFunction -> 
        {{Hue[Random[]], Disk[Print["VSF"]; #1, 0.05]} & }}]]
```

where we can see that the colors are supposed to be generated randomly by the option `VertexShapeFunction`.

However, after evaluating

```
ClearSystemCache[];
```

evaluating g will (almost almost surely ;) ) yield a graph with a new colors.

[this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11029/can-a-colorfunction-have-side-effects) seems related.

**My question is**: How can we turn off such caching?

We can find systemoptions having to do with Cache by evaluating

```
SystemOptions["Cache*"]
```

but setting all the rules of the form

```
"Cache"-> True
```

to

```
"Cache" -> False
```

does not change the way the graphics behave.

They do however influence the value of

```
Timing[N[Pi, 1000000]][[1]]
```

The SystemOptions can be set by evaluating

```
SetSystemOptions["CacheOptions" -> "Developer" -> "Cache" -> False];
SetSystemOptions["CacheOptions" -> "Numeric" -> "Cache" -> False];
SetSystemOptions[
  "CacheOptions" -> "ParametricFunction" -> "Cache" -> False];
SetSystemOptions["CacheOptions" -> "Quantity" -> "Cache" -> False];
SetSystemOptions["CacheOptions" -> "Symbolic" -> "Cache" -> False];
```

Comment: Yay, thanks for the upvote, 1000 rep :D

Comment: Sorry, that was mine, but had to unupvote because I can't reproduce your observations. Since `Graphics` isn't `HoldAll`, the color will be determined when `gr` is set and does not change thereafter whether the cache is cleared or not. Using `SetDelayed` to define `gr` (or adding `Unevaluated`) similarly produces the expected result.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thank you, I fixed things by just considering the graph examples and removing my hypothesis that all Graphics get cached.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn off caching in graphs by setting the system options:

```
SetSystemOptions["GraphOptions" -> "CacheResults" -> False]
```

Comment: Nice, this works. It is nice to see they added this option in version 10. Thank you for going back to my old question.